# User data through Google APIs without authorization flow

Tags: heroku, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-authentication, google-api-python-client

I'm writing a web application that reads my personal calendar data, crunches stats, and then spits them out for the world to see. I don't need an authorization flow. Is it possible to leverage the Google APIs without going through a user sign-in flow? In other words, **I want my personal Google account permanently and securely signed in to my server without the risk of my token invalidating or having to re-auth**.

Right now I'm signing myself in with an offline token, then uploading the authorization file onto my server, basically spoofing the server that I already auth'd. Is there not a cleaner way?

I've spent hours reading through the API docs and Auth docs, but haven't found and answer. If there is a page I've missed, please point me to it!

PS. I'm using the Calendars API through Python/Flask on Heroku, but that shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative approach is using a service account while sharing your calendar with that service account. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount

Comment: A service account, when impersonating a elevated user account (typically a superadmin), can read and write any calendar within the domain. There is no need to share the calendar with anybody.

Comment: That is true but first of all how do you know this account is owned by a domain and second of all if this is an app for personal use then I would strongly advice against this service account to have access to the entire domain.

Comment: Service accounts have access to scopes, which may be read/write or read-only. Service account are a different concept from user account since they can impersonate ANY user account.

Comment: You were assuming that OP refers to a Google Apps account even when OP talks about a "personal account".

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding. I did by no means assume that it's a domain owned account. My point is that if you don't want to store directly your Oauth refresh tokens somewhere on a server, you could also give the service account the access to exactly what it needs and then you perform the stats processing job using that service account.

Comment: Yes, there was. We use services accounts in a Google Apps domain and we do always impersonate users. I didn't realize that service accounts could be used like that (i.e.: you can share something with them). I would happily change my vote on this answer but needs to be edited to do so.

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to be **remembered**.

If you want to dispose of any kind of authenticacion but yet the user needs to be recognized you should be using a cookie.

On the server side that cookie should be used to select the offline token.

Of course, without that cookie the user needs to be authenticated in any way. I would make them reauth by Google so you get a new offline token.

Hope that it helps.